# How to make text field in flutter can insert images

Tags: flutter, textfield

How to make text field look like image below, can insert images or emoticons? Because default text field in flutter only input text.
[image: look like this]

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Anyone find anything?

Comment: Until now, I have not found a solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You should be follow below link

> [Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want to display image inline the text field, it's possible?