# Convert string to emoji in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

I have strings in JSON that looks like

> "\ud83d\ude09"

This is escaped representation of emojis. Example above is [winking face](https://www.charbase.com/1f609-unicode-winking-face). 
I want to present this emojis in Flutter's `Text` widget, how it can be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter)