# Flutter: TextField with emoji not working properly

Tags: flutter, emoji

I want to use emoji in TextField, but emoji does not working properly. If I input character next to emoji, the emoji changes something like to "?", "?character?".

This is the video: https://twitter.com/LainNao/status/1231695776465608706

Is there any solution or workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying text with Emojis on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter)

Comment: @Alex Meuer　My problem and your url's problem seems similar but different to me. But thank you!