# Replace all element by image in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to replace all patterns in a string by Flutter `Image.network`.

I do this:

```
String text = ":smiley: very goog"
text.replaceAll(":smiley:", Image.Network(src))
```

It does not work because `replaceAll` second argument must a text not a widget.

Comment: Can you describe your use-case ? what you would achieve ?

Comment: If the aim is to display emoji in a Text, it is supported by Flutter. I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter

Comment: I'm agree but when i develop my website i allow user to put emoji with emoji code for example :smiley: and i replace code by picture, so in my flutter app i want to replace code by image.network Thank.