# Flutter - TextField not showing emojis

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app where the user can insert a description on profile information.
The field is a normal `TextField` and not showing the emojis that the user insert in the field.

How can I show the emojis on that field?

Thank you.

Comment: show this article
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter

Comment: I solved with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned what you are using?  There is a package `emoji_pick 0.1.0`  and sample usage is there on the official page. Refer here:https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_pick

Comment: I try to explain me better. The user can insert emojis and he can see the emoji keyboard, but when he save the field, the emojis are not showed. It seems the emojis are not saved :(