# Emojis are not getting displayed in text received from api call, flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, emoji

I am trying to display text which includes emojis from a string received in API response. The text is displaying properly but the emojis are getting displayed as some foreign characters. Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks.

**Emojis in the text should be like this**:  'So, how are you finding this app? 
Spare a min to rate it.'

But it is getting displayed as below.

[image: Screen shot of emulator]

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter/56839834#56839834).

Answer (score 10):

Pass your string in this method!

```
String utf8convert(String text) {
    List<int> bytes = text.toString().codeUnits;
    return utf8.decode(bytes);
  }
```