# FittedBox with single emoji in text not showing up

Tags: flutter, dart, render, emoji, scaling

My beloved  is not showing up. It used to though, with Flutter 3.0.0.

Now, using Flutter 3.3.6 Dart SDK 2.18.2, it does not.

Does anyone know if it's a bug? Or does anyone know a workaround for auto-scaling?

**Minimal example:**

```
class OtterFreakshow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      Column(children: [
        // works as expected with single letters
        Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      width:200, height: 200 ,child: const FittedBox(child: Text('A'))),
              
        // works as expected for emoji with surrounding letters
                Container(color: Colors.purple,
      width:200, height: 200 ,child: const FittedBox(child: Text('__'))),
        
        // not rendering correctly (invisible!) without some letters surrounding the otter
        Container(color: Colors.red,
      width:200, height: 200 ,child: const FittedBox(child: Text('')))
      
      
      ]);
    }}
```

yields:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/n87grh6na3n2dfj/Screenshot%202022-11-01%20at%2019.42.29.png?dl=0

Interestingly, with surrounding blankspaces, the emoji also does not show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it. Also I can clearly see the emoji when I run it in dartpad.

[image]

**Still if you feel unsafe about it,**

Use [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) plugin

If you wanna automatically resize fonts based on parent widget's width and height, using [`auto_size_text`](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package is the best option. It's really easy to use and has rich documentation.

Sample Usage:

```
AutoSizeText(
  'The text to display',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
  maxLines: 2,
)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.:) It's really odd, because my dartpad has the above described issue :O I don't see any difference! 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/04bxjqc6c5w2x5u/Screenshot%202022-11-01%20at%2020.45.54.png?dl=0

Comment: I see. So it's a bug. You can reference here for custom emojis and richtext: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56839834/19209151