# Creating a custom Emoji Keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, emoji, rich-text-editor, custom-keyboard, richtext

I'm trying to create a custom emoji set inside my social app.
I'm not sure what is the right way to do it
but I think I can do that by creating a map of images and some unique codes
for example {"#123":"cat.png","#777":"dog.png"}
And then create my Emoji picker which is basically a grid
but I'm not sure how I can display the Images inside the TextFormField on typing or the Text on viewing the post later
I think that maybe something like RichText could be useful.
any Ideas or suggestions?
Thanks a lot for your time reading I hope you have a nice day

I tried to find helpful tutorials on Youtube [the kind of keyboard I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Xj9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

#### If you want your own json, you can take reference from this

take a look at this [Codepen of emoji](https://codepen.io/housamz/pen/abZZxxO)
they have used a json

```
[{
      "category": "smileys_people",
      "shortcode": ":smile:",
      "keywords": "happy smiley smileys emotion emotions emotional emotion emotions emotional",
      "data-clipboard-text": "",
      "data-emoji": "",
      "title": "Smiling Face with Open Mouth and Smiling Eyes",
      "#text": ""
    }]
```

they are using #text value in their span. maybe can add a .png or any image format, but you'll have to make sure you place it in a image

#### if you don't want custom emoji, there are twitter emojis

[codepen of twitter emoji](https://codepen.io/DerkJanS/pen/MbrRwW)

heres a [flutter twitter emoji pacakge](https://github.com/hadi-codes/twemoji)

take a [look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936239/displaying-text-with-emojis-on-flutter) maybe their answer might be helpful